# RegEx to isolate the numbers from string [Paragraph 1, 2, 3 and 4 refer to blah-blah.]

Tags: regex

I am trying to build create a list of the numbers stated in a string with specific format:

> Paragraph 1, 2, 3 and 4 refer to blah-blah. Paragraph 5 refers to blah-blah.

The expected output should be two lists [1,2,3,4] and [5].

I've tried the following RegEx: `r"(?:Section)\s+(\d)((?:,\s*\d)*)(?:\s*and\s*)?(\d)*"`, being stuck on the pattern for repeat match `((?:,\s*\d)*)`, returning Group 2 as `, 2, 3`:

```
Match 1: 1
Group 1: 1
Group 2: , 2, 3
Group 3: 4

Match 2: 1
Group 1: 5
```

What I'd like to get is:

```
Match 1: 1
Group 1: 1
Group 2: 2
Group 3: 3
Group 4: 4

Match 1: 1
Group 1: 5
```

Could someone please give me a hint?

Thank you.

Comment: It is correct. This is how it works. To be able to access individual captures use PyPi regex and `match.captures(groupID)`.

Comment: How about just `Regex.Replace("[^P0-9 ]", "")` which will reduce the string to something like `"P 1 2 3 4 P 5` then you can split on P, then spaces